# How to write sql to select with IF else to Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

How can I write a query to fetch a field using `if else` condition. Here is the query I have tried.

```
 $sql = $this->db->select()
            ->from(array('GE' => 'global_edits'), array('member_id'))
            ->joinLeft(array('A' => 'advertiser_revision'), 'GE.member_id=A.member_id', array())
            ->joinLeft(array('MC' => 'member'), 'MC.id=GE.created_by', array())
            ->joinLeft(array('M' => 'member'), 'M.id=GE.member_id', array('email_member' => 'email'));

    $sql->where('GE.status=?', $status);
    $sql->group('GE.id');
    $sql->columns(array('A.member_id', 'GE.created', 'GE.rev_id', 'GE.created_by', 'GE.status', 'email_created' => 'MC.email'));

   return $sql;
```

The field `GE.created _by` may be 0 in some cases. In that case I have to use the field `email_member`

```
if(GE.created _by == 0) email_member else GE.created _by
```

How can I implement this using zend ?

Comment: I guess you can not able to do it directly you need to use [Zend_Db_Expr](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Db/Expr/Zend_Db_Expr.html) to achieve that.

Comment: Custom query using`$db->query` or use `ZEnd_Db_Expr` no direct way I guess.